# Make Cmd+C do both Copy and Stop in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Left control Key located in a very unpleasant place on my Mac keyboard.
It's hard to reach in the terminal.
Luckily, I don't need it very often: I have Cmd for **most** of the things.
There are few cases, where I need it:

Ctrl+R for reverse history search
Ctrl+C to kill a process or discard a line

I found [Karabiner](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner) and it helped with reverse history search [remapping](https://github.com/vors/karabiner-fu#terminal).
But Ctrl+C puzzles me.

I know that on unix I can use Ctrl+C for both Stop and Copy in the terminal. And it determines what to do from the context: if there is anything selected, copy it. Otherwise, stop command or discard the user input line.

How I can achieve it on OS X with Cmd key?

Comment: On systems like Debian, Copy is remapped to Shift+Ctrl+C. Would you like something like that, or how would you like to distinguish the 2 operations? I might have a solution in mind, which does not quite involve distinguishment through context of the keystroke.

Comment: @TheBro21 I would prefer to have it without Shift, because that's how it works in OS X everywhere else. Also I use rdp a lot and on windows machines I just remapped Cmd to Ctrl and it works great, so it's already a old habit.

Comment: I see. I'll try posting my solution as a temporary workaround until a better one is found.

Answer (score 1):

#### The temporary workaround to this

---

It is possible to remap keys on any program in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**. Click the plus icon, and select terminal in the application drop down. Then type the name of the function (**Copy** in this case), and then highlight the shortcut box, and press a desired combination. The window should look something like so:

[image]

The above is just an example. This can be applied to virtually any situation and application